# How to link an ID generated URL to the <a href> tag

Tags: python, html, django

I am making my own portfolio website using Django.. So the idea is:  Make posts containing websites that i've developed. All these posts will be displayed in a page called "Projects" and then you can access a single project to read about it. Every project i upload have an ID, so i used this code to acess each project page:

```
# Single project page
    path('projects/<int:post_id>/', views.project, name='project'),
```

Then in my PROJECTS page i have a simple(for now) HTML code to show all my projects and link them to the single project page. What i want to know is how to LINK this ID generated URL in this code:

```
<ul>
  {% for project in projects %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ project }}</a></li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>No project have been added yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I tried using:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'main_portfolio/projects/<int:post_id>/' %}</a></li
```

And some other things but nothing i try is working.

Comment: `{% url 'project' project.pk %}`

Comment: Thank you Willem, you've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `<a href="{{ project.get_absolute_url }}">`, or
`<a href="projects/{{ project.id }}/">`

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<li><a href="{% url 'project' project.pk %}">some text</a></li>
```